# How to output signed variable

Tags: c++, variables, formatting, output, sign

How do I print signed value of my variable?
For example:

```
int main()
{
    int variable_name = 2;
    cout<<variable_name<<endl;
}
```

I want this code to print +2, not just 2. And I don't want to use such construction:

```
cout<<"+"<<variable_name<<endl;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::showpos` is what you're looking for:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/showpos/