# Representing ax+by equations in C compiler

Tags: c

Hi everyone I am trying to represent linear equations in C and when I give a negative
coefficient it look like *ax + -by* is there anyway to represent it like *ax - by*  without using `if` `else`'s?
thanks  a lot. (using devc++)

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
     
     int x_coefficient, y_coefficient,x,y;
     printf("Please Enter X and Y's  coefficients ");
     scanf("%d %d", &x_coefficient, &y_coefficient);
     
     printf("\n Your equation is %dx + %dy", x_coefficient, y_coefficient);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: Better how?

Comment: Print the first coefficient. Then print `+` if the second coefficient is positive. Then print the second coefficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to output signed variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494277/how-to-output-signed-variable)

Comment: @Ben_LCDB The linked question and answers are for C++ not C.

Comment: Sorry for the question's uncertainty i meant how i can represent it ax - by. Thanks for your helping

Comment: i really appreciate your helping and understanding being  new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to do this without using `if`/`else` or other conditional statements would be to change the `printf` format string.

```c
    printf("\n Your equation is %dx %+dy", x_coefficient, y_coefficient);
```

The flag `+` forces a sign character to be prepended to the number.

Citing https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

> - **+**: the sign of signed conversions is always prepended to the result of the conversion (by default the result is preceded by minus only when it is negative)

This would print something like

```
Your equation is 2x +3y
Your equation is 2x -3y
```

Unfortunately this does not allow to print a space between the `+` or `-` and the second number, so you cannot get something like `2x + 3y` instead of `2x +3y`.

BTW: If you don't plan to append to the same line of `printf` output I suggest to add a trailing `\n`.

Comment: Thanks For your helping and advice,Best regards.